# Unable to access aliased fields in SQLAlchemy query results?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Confused working with query object results.  I am not using foreign keys in this example.

```
lookuplocation = aliased(ValuePair)

lookupoccupation = aliased(ValuePair)

persons = db.session.query(Person.lastname, lookuplocation.displaytext, lookupoccupation.displaytext).\
         outerjoin(lookuplocation, Person.location == lookuplocation.valuepairid).\
         outerjoin(lookupoccupation, Person.occupation1 == lookupoccupation.valuepairid).all()
```

Results are correct as far as data is concerned.  However, when I try to access an individual row of data I have an issue:

persons[0].lastname works as I expected and returns data.

However, there is a person.displaytext in the result but since I aliased the displaytext entity, I get just one result.  I understand why I get the result but I need to know what aliased field names I would use to get the two displaytext columns.

The actual SQL statement generated by the above join is as follows:

```
SELECT person.lastname AS person_lastname, valuepair_1.displaytext AS valuepair_1_displaytext, valuepair_2.displaytext AS valuepair_2_displaytext 
FROM person LEFT OUTER JOIN valuepair AS valuepair_1 ON person.location = valuepair_1.valuepairid LEFT OUTER JOIN valuepair AS valuepair_2 ON person.occupation1 = valuepair_2.valuepairid
```

But none of these "as" field names are available to me in the results.

I'm new to SqlAlchemy so most likely this is a "newbie" issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - RTFM issue - should have been:

lookuplocation.displaytext.label("myfield1"), 
lookupoccupation.displaytext.label("myfield2")

After results are returned reference field with person.myfield

Simple.